# math notation question regarding location within ordered set

Tags: notation

if $\{x_i\}$ for $i=1...N$ are a set of ordered values such that $x_1\ge x_2 \ge ... \ge x_N$ how do I notate most efficiently for a given number $y$ where $x_1 \ge y \ge x_N$ the maximum subscript $j$ such that $x_j \ge y \ge x_{j+1}$

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would write $$j^* = \max \{j : x_j \geq y \geq x_{j+1}\}.$$  Of course, there's also nothing wrong with the way you defined it in words.

Comment: does that notation make it clear that the $x_j$ are ordered?

Comment: No, I assumed that was stated beforehand.

Comment: (to be clear, the use of $j^*$ is not a special notation that implies anything -  you can call that variable whatever you like.)